# Ошибка Repository is unrelated когда пушу репозиторий с саб-репозиторием

Tags: bitbucket, mercurial

Я создал главный репозиторий, клонировал в него другой репозиторий и назначил его саб репозиторием.

Но когда я пушу главный репозиторий в bitbucket то получаю ошибку:

> pushing to https://bitbucket.org/user/main-repo
>
> pushing subrepo Assets\Plugins\GameFramework to https://bitbucket.org/user/main-repo/Assets/Plugins/GameFramework
>
> searching for changes
>
> прервано: repository is unrelated (in subrepo Assets\Plugins\GameFramework)

Сейчас у меня в ошибке почему-то пишет просто "repository is unrelated".

Странно, но если после ошибки стрипнуть все коммиты в bitbucket репозитории и снова запушить, то все сработает.
Я снял видео своих действий https://youtu.be/WI86_3I2ZH0

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно изменить .hgsub файл. По умолчанию TortoiseHG создает файл следующего формата:

```
[folder to sub repo] = [folder to sub repo]
```

Нужно изменить это на:

```
[folder to sub repo] = [sub repo url]
```